# Scraping Reelgood.com in python with Beautifullsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to build a scraper (in Python) for the website [ReelGood.com](https://reelgood.com/movies/source/netflix).

If I go to a specific movie on Reelgood it shows me a play button like this:
[Stream button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZxmQ.png)

If I click that button it redirects me for example to https://www.netflix.com/title/70232180
now I would like to scrape that specific URL. so I thought I make a small python script to scrape all links that contains https://netflix.com/x.

so I came up with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://reelgood.com/movie/the-intouchables-2011"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for a_href in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    print(a_href["href"])
```

now this does give me a print from all the links but there are no links containing the url witch im redirected to.

anyone got an idea how to spit out the Netflix.com url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter for links that only contain `https://www.netflix.com/`, you can use a CSS Selector: `a[href*="https://www.netflix.com/"]`, which will select all `a` with an `href` containing `https://www.netflix.com/`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://reelgood.com/movie/the-intouchables-2011"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for a_href in soup.select('a[href*="https://www.netflix.com/"]'):
    print(a_href["href"])
```

Output:

```
https://www.netflix.com/watch/70232180
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but if you run the script it doesn't find the Netflix URL. while it has to be there somewhere

Comment: @JohnDoe It works for me. Does it appear when you do `print(soup.prettify())`?

Comment: My bad, u where right for that example it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use my code addapt it to your needs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import time
from pprint import pprint

```
# instantiate a new Nominatim client
app = Nominatim(user_agent="tutorial")

def getLocation():
    #autoriser le naviagateur pour acceder à l'emplacement actuelle par defaut,
    # Si on essaye d'accéder à un site Web : « https://mycurrentlocation.net » via chrome,
    # il demande d'autoriser l'accès à la localisation. La commande « - use-fake-ui-for-media-stream »
    # accordera toutes les autorisations pour l'emplacement, le microphone, etc. automatiquement.
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    # appelez la page Web https://mycurrentlocation.net/ et attendez 20 secondes que la page se charge.
    timeout = 20
    #Pour chromedriver il faut avoir la meme version que google chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = './chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = './chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options) -> on peut mettre ça a la palce
    driver.get("https://mycurrentlocation.net/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    time.sleep(3)
    #Trouvez le XPath des éléments de latitude et de longitude mentionnés sur la page Web puis copier le nom de la classe qu'on souhaite récupérer
    neighborhood = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="neighborhood"]')
    neighborhood = [x.text for x in neighborhood]
    neighborhood = str(neighborhood[0])

    regionname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="regionname"]')
    regionname = [x.text for x in regionname]
    regionname = str(regionname[0])

    placename = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="placename"]')
    placename = [x.text for x in placename]
    placename = str(placename[0])

    driver.quit()
    return (neighborhood,regionname,placename)

neighborhood,regionname,placename=getLocation()

print("le résultat est : \n ",
    neighborhood,regionname,placename)
```