# Scrape url list from Reelgood.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi Im trying to build a scraper (in Python) for the website ReelGood.com.

now I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66745027/scraping-reelgood-com-in-python-with-beautifullsoup/66746815?noredirect=1#comment117989392_66746815) topic to and I figured out how to scrape the url from the movie page. but what I can't seem t figure out why this script won't work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import requests

URL = "https://reelgood.com/movies/source/netflix"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

f = open("C:/Downloaders/test/Scrape/test1.txt", "w")
for link in soup.select('a[href*="https://reelgood.com/movie/"]'):
    data = link.get('href')
    f.write(data)
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

**EDIT**
The end goal is to export a txt file containing all links to the movie page on reelgood.com.

**UPDATE: 1**

if I change the script to this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import requests

URL = "https://reelgood.com/movies/source/netflix"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

f = open("C:/Downloaders/test/Scrape/test1.txt", "w")
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    data = link.get('href')
    f.write(data)
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

i do get the following output in test1.txt

```
/ /tv /tv/curated/trending-picks /tv/browse/new-tv-on-your-sources /tv/roulette/netflix /tv?filter-availability=onSources /tv/source/free /tv/source/netflix /tv/source/amazon /tv/source/hulu /tv/curated/2019-emmy-nominees /tv/genre/action-and-adventure /tv/genre/animation /tv/genre/anime /tv/genre/comedy /tv/genre/crime /tv/genre/documentary /tv/genre/drama /tv/genre/food /tv/genre/family /tv/genre/fantasy /tv/curated/imdbs-best-rated-tv /tv/genre/lgbtq /tv/genre/mystery /tv/genre/reality /tv/genre/science-fiction /tv /movies /movies/browse/popular-movies /movies/browse/recent-movies-on-your-sources /movies/roulette/netflix /movies?filter-availability=onSources /movies/source/free /movies/source/netflix /movies/source/amazon /movies/source/hulu /movies/genre/action-and-adventure /movies/genre/animation /movies/genre/comedy /movies/genre/crime /movies/genre/documentary /movies/genre/drama /movies/genre/family /movies/genre/fantasy /movies/genre/horror /movies/curated/imdbs-best-rated-movies /movies/genre/lgbtq /movies/genre/mystery /movies/genre/romance /movies/genre/science-fiction /movies/genre/thriller /movies /new /new?availability=onSources /new/netflix /new/amazon /new/hulu /new/hbo /new/disney_plus /coming?availability=onSources /coming/netflix /coming/amazon /coming/hulu /coming/hbo /coming/disney_plus /leaving?availability=onSources /leaving/netflix /leaving/amazon /leaving/hulu /leaving/hbo /new /login /login /signup /movies/source/netflix /movies/genre/action-and-adventure/on-netflix /movies/genre/animation/on-netflix /movies/genre/anime/on-netflix /movies/genre/biography/on-netflix /movies/genre/children/on-netflix /movies/genre/comedy/on-netflix /movies/genre/crime/on-netflix /movies/genre/cult/on-netflix /movies/genre/documentary/on-netflix /movies/genre/drama/on-netflix /movies/genre/family/on-netflix /movies/genre/fantasy/on-netflix /movies/genre/food/on-netflix /movies/genre/history/on-netflix /movies/genre/horror/on-netflix /movies/genre/lgbtq/on-netflix /movies/genre/musical/on-netflix /movies/genre/mystery/on-netflix /movies/genre/romance/on-netflix /movies/genre/science-fiction/on-netflix /movies/genre/sport/on-netflix /movies/genre/stand-up-and-talk/on-netflix /movies/genre/thriller/on-netflix /movies/list/africa/on-netflix /movies/list/adaptation/on-netflix /movies/list/alien/on-netflix /movies/list/animal/on-netflix /movies/list/apocalypse/on-netflix /movies/list/baseball/on-netflix /movies/list/based-on-novel/on-netflix /movies/list/true-story/on-netflix /movies/list/bollywood/on-netflix /movies/list/boxing/on-netflix /movies/list/british-humour/on-netflix /movies/list/car/on-netflix /movies/list/cartoon/on-netflix /movies/list/christmas/on-netflix /movies/list/classic/on-netflix /movies/list/college/on-netflix /movies/list/based-on-comic/on-netflix /movies/list/coming-of-age/on-netflix /movies/list/dance/on-netflix /movies/list/dark-comedy/on-netflix /movies/list/dating/on-netflix /movies/list/disaster/on-netflix /movies/list/disney/on-netflix /movies/list/doctor/on-netflix /movies/list/dog/on-netflix /movies/list/drug/on-netflix /movies/list/dystopia/on-netflix /movies/list/egypt/on-netflix /movies/list/escape/on-netflix /movies/list/fashion/on-netflix /movies/list/feel-good/on-netflix /movies/list/woman-director/on-netflix /movies/list/fighting/on-netflix /movies/list/friendship/on-netflix /movies/list/futuristic/on-netflix /movies/list/gang/on-netflix /movies/list/gangster/on-netflix /movies/list/genius/on-netflix /movies/list/ghost/on-netflix /movies/list/golf/on-netflix /movies/list/gymnast/on-netflix /movies/list/heroism/on-netflix /movies/list/high-school/on-netflix /movies/list/holiday/on-netflix /movies/list/hunting/on-netflix /movies/list/imagination/on-netflix /movies/list/jungle/on-netflix /movies/list/kidnapping/on-netflix /movies/list/magic/on-netflix /movies/list/martial-arts/on-netflix /movies/list/mature/on-netflix /movies/list/medieval/on-netflix /movies/list/military/on-netflix /movies/list/monster/on-netflix /movies/list/music/on-netflix /movies/list/new-york/on-netflix /movies/list/paris/on-netflix /movies/list/parody/on-netflix /movies/list/pet/on-netflix /movies/list/police/on-netflix /movies/list/political/on-netflix /movies/list/princess/on-netflix /movies/list/prison/on-netflix /movies/list/psychology/on-netflix /movies/list/racing/on-netflix /movies/list/religion/on-netflix /movies/list/revenge/on-netflix /movies/list/river/on-netflix /movies/list/robot/on-netflix /movies/list/rome/on-netflix /movies/list/royalty/on-netflix /movies/list/science/on-netflix /movies/list/serial-killer/on-netflix /movies/list/short/on-netflix /movies/list/singing/on-netflix /movies/list/space/on-netflix /movies/list/sports/on-netflix /movies/list/spy/on-netflix /movies/list/superhero/on-netflix /movies/list/supernatural/on-netflix /movies/list/survival/on-netflix /movies/list/suspense/on-netflix /movies/list/tank/on-netflix /movies/list/teacher/on-netflix /movies/list/technology/on-netflix /movies/list/teen/on-netflix /movies/list/time-travel/on-netflix /movies/list/toy/on-netflix /movies/list/twins/on-netflix /movies/list/vampire/on-netflix /movies/list/games/on-netflix /movies/list/war/on-netflix /movies/list/world-war-ii/on-netflix /movies/list/wrestling/on-netflix /movies/list/zombie/on-netflix /source/netflix /movies/source/netflix /tv/source/netflix /movies /movies/source/free /movies /movies/source/netflix /movies/source/amazon /movies/source/hbo_max /movies/source/hbo /movies/source/showtime /movies/source/hulu /movies/source/fx_tveverywhere /movies/source/starz /movies/source/apple_tv_plus /movies/source/plex_free /movies/source/disney_plus /movies/source/peacock /movies/source/philo /movies/source/fubo_tv /movies/source/epix /movies/source/crunchyroll_premium /movies/source/dc_universe /movies/source/mubi /movies/source/discovery_plus /movies/source/amc_premiere /movies/source/amc /movies/source/britbox /movies/source/ifc /movies/source/youtube_premium /movies/source/shudder /movies/source/criterion_channel /movies/source/funimation /movies/source/fandor /movies/source/hoopla /movies/source/kanopy /movies/source/tubi_tv /movies/source/plutotv /movies/source/peacock_free /movies/source/vudu_free /movies/source/imdb_tv /movies/source/popcornflix /movies/source/crunchyroll_free /movies/source/crackle /movies/source/acorntv /movies/source/cinemax /movies/source/hallmark_movies_now /movies/source/sundance_tveverywhere /movies/source/syfy_tveverywhere /movies/source/tbs /movies/source/tnt /movies/source/bet_plus /movies/source/watch_tcm /movies/source/comedycentral_tveverywhere /movies/source/hallmark_everywhere /movies/source/lifetime_tveverywhere /movies/source/disneynow /movies/source/paramount_plus /movies/source/tvision /movie/the-intouchables-2011 /movie/the-intouchables-2011 /movie/the-irishman-2018 /movie/the-irishman-2018 /movie/marriage-story-2019 /movie/marriage-story-2019 /movie/dangal-2016 /movie/dangal-2016 /movie/the-invisible-guest-2017 /movie/the-invisible-guest-2017 /movie/scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world-2010 /movie/scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world-2010 /movie/david-attenborough-a-life-on-our-planet-2020 /movie/david-attenborough-a-life-on-our-planet-2020 /movie/a-silent-voice-2016 /movie/a-silent-voice-2016 /movie/13th-2016 /movie/13th-2016 /movie/the-dark-knight-2008 /movie/the-dark-knight-2008 /movie/icarus-2017 /movie/icarus-2017 /movie/roma-2018 /movie/roma-2018 /movie/black-mirror-bandersnatch-2018 /movie/black-mirror-bandersnatch-2018 /movie/inception-2010 /movie/inception-2010 /movie/the-two-popes-2019 /movie/the-two-popes-2019 /movie/the-trial-of-the-chicago-7-2020 /movie/the-trial-of-the-chicago-7-2020 /movie/to-all-the-boys-ive-loved-before-2018 /movie/to-all-the-boys-ive-loved-before-2018 /movie/pk-2014 /movie/pk-2014 /movie/the-social-dilemma-2020 /movie/the-social-dilemma-2020 /movie/fruitvale-station-2013 /movie/fruitvale-station-2013 /movie/the-ballad-of-buster-scruggs-2018 /movie/the-ballad-of-buster-scruggs-2018 /movie/the-dawn-wall-2018 /movie/the-dawn-wall-2018 /movie/dolemite-is-my-name-2019 /movie/dolemite-is-my-name-2019 /movie/okja-2017 /movie/okja-2017 /movie/article-15-2019 /movie/article-15-2019 /movie/jim-andy-the-great-beyond-featuring-a-very-special-contractually-obligated-mention-of-tony-clifton-2017 /movie/jim-andy-the-great-beyond-featuring-a-very-special-contractually-obligated-mention-of-tony-clifton-2017 /movie/mudbound-2017 /movie/mudbound-2017 /movie/the-croods-2013 /movie/the-croods-2013 /movie/enola-holmes-2020 /movie/enola-holmes-2020 /movie/the-end-of-evangelion-1997 /movie/the-end-of-evangelion-1997 /movie/miss-americana-2020 /movie/miss-americana-2020 /movie/fyre-the-greatest-party-that-never-happened-2019 /movie/fyre-the-greatest-party-that-never-happened-2019 /movie/the-platform-2019 /movie/the-platform-2019 /movie/swades-we-the-people-2004 /movie/swades-we-the-people-2004 /movie/the-king-2019 /movie/the-king-2019 /movie/pieces-of-a-woman-2020 /movie/pieces-of-a-woman-2020 /movie/the-departed-2006 /movie/the-departed-2006 /movie/django-unchained-2012 /movie/django-unchained-2012 /movie/i-am-mother-2019 /movie/i-am-mother-2019 /movie/disclosure-trans-lives-on-screen-2020 /movie/disclosure-trans-lives-on-screen-2020 /movie/bo-burnham-make-happy-2016 /movie/bo-burnham-make-happy-2016 /movie/haider-2014 /movie/haider-2014 /movie/virunga-2014 /movie/virunga-2014 /movie/john-mulaney-kid-gorgeous-at-radio-city-2018 /movie/john-mulaney-kid-gorgeous-at-radio-city-2018 /movie/the-half-of-it-2020 /movie/the-half-of-it-2020 /movie/the-square-2013 /movie/the-square-2013 /movie/shutter-island-2010 /movie/shutter-island-2010 /movie/snowden-2016 /movie/snowden-2016 /movie/i-lost-my-body-2019 /movie/i-lost-my-body-2019 /movie/the-boy-who-harnessed-the-wind-2019 /movie/the-boy-who-harnessed-the-wind-2019 /movies/source/netflix?offset=50 https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reelgood-tv-guide-for-streaming/id1031391869 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reelgoodapp.reelgood&referrer=utm_source%3DReelgoodWebApp%26utm_medium%3DGetAppPopUp%26utm_term%3DGetAppPopUp%26utm_content%3DGetAppPopUp%26utm_campaign%3DGetAppPopUp%26anid%3Dadmob /roulette/netflix /swipe /browse/popular-movies /curated/popular-picks /source/free /all /source/netflix /new/netflix /source/hulu /new/hulu /source/hbo /new/hbo /source/amazon /new/amazon /sitemap /about /business/products/catalog/ /tos /privacy-policy https://blog.reelgood.com /careers /faq / https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reelgood-tv-guide-for-streaming/id1031391869 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reelgoodapp.reelgood&referrer=utm_source%3DReelgoodWepApp%26utm_content%3DFooter%26utm_campaign%3DGetAndroidApp%26anid%3Dadmob
```

So this outputs all the links found. but misses the base url.

**UPDATE: 2**

movie url's are as follow: `<a href="/movie/the-movie-name-2021">`

Comment: What does "this script won't work" mean? How exactly does it not work?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. The script supposed to write all links (urls) containing: https://reelgood.com/movie/ in to the text file: test1.txt. but it doesn't show an error and the output stays empty while the url cointains loads of links to a specific movie.

Comment: Assign `soup.select` result to a temporary variable and print it to show that it returns anything to loop over

Comment: how would you suggest I do that? sorry im no expert in python or beautifullsoup.

Comment: @JohnDoe, basically, `print(soup.select('a[href*="https://reelgood.com/movie/"]'))`. Looks like `soup.select` didn't find anything

Comment: @ForceBru thanks! but the links are there like in the example when I do `soup.find_all` any idea how to extract them? the ones containing [link](https://reelgood.com/movie/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of attribute = value selectors to target the elements which have the full url in the content attribute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://reelgood.com/movies/source/netflix"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select('[itemprop=itemListElement] [itemprop=url]'):
    print(link['content'])
```

Comment: Thanks this really works good! only got issue left it doesn't scrape all url's. probably because there is a button load more. I tried to offset the url but that doesn't seem to work. also I dont see an option to click a button in bs4.

Comment: well I would like to scrape all movies, for Netflix these are atm 3787 movies.
btw when all the items are listed the bar load more disappears.